# Retrieving names of drug that include spaces from specific adverse reactions

Tags: openfda

I am trying to extract the top 100 drugs related to the highest number of adverse reaction of a specific type.

For example, I would like to extract the top 100 drugs that have been reported as associated with the adverse reaction "nausea".

The query I use is the following:

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt:nausea&limit=100&count=patient.drug.activesubstance.activesubstancename
```

The problem is that, for compound names that include a space, the two terms are reported as separate (e.g. "HYDROXYZINE HYDROCHLORIDE" is reported as "HYDROXYZINE" and "HYDROCHLORIDE"). As a consequence, "hydrochloride" is obviously reported on top for most of the compounds just for being the most used solvent in compound names, but the list goes on also for multiple other solvents.

How can I extract the complete compound names from the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Jack with the openFDA team. Your query is just missing one modifier: `.exact`. I'm posting a fixed version of your example below. My apologies for the very delayed response.

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt:nausea&limit=100&count=patient.drug.activesubstance.activesubstancename.exact